# Why is the following attribute not found in Enum?

Tags: python, enums

I am using Python 2.7.5 and I installed Enum as

`pip install Enum`

I have written out the following code to test Enum.

```
from enum import Enum
class Color(Enum):
  red = 'Hello'
  blue = 'Trello'
  green = 'Yello'

for name, attr in Color.__members__.items():
  print(attr.value)
```

This throws me an error saying.

`AttributeError: type object 'Color' has no attribute '__members__'`.

Why is python not able to get `__members__` ?

Comment: Because it doesn't exist.

Comment: But then is Enum not backported

Comment: If you need to install it from PyPI then it hasn't been backported. Especially since it was created in 2009.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I don't understand your comment -- many new Python features are backported and put on PyPI.

Comment: @EthanFurman: "Backported" implies that they're part of the language proper, not some module that needs to be installed from somewhere else.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: When this question was asked, `Enum` was part of the language proper (starting with 3.4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing [`enum`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum/) with [`enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html). They have many similarities, but are not the same thing. In particular, the attribute you're looking for does not exist.

Answer (score 10):

You need to use the [enum34 backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34):

```
pip install enum34
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to install enum34 to get key value pair

```
yum install python-enum34
```

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).